# Logging into Facebook with a batch job

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I am attempting to build a batch process that collects certain information off of my own Facebook account nightly. Offline_access has been deprecated. I have been working on following the process here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/

and directly POSTing to the OAuth dialog, but it occurs to me that this might be a TOC violation.

Is there a new process for automated login to Facebook that I can not find?

Comment: I might have answered my own question with the access_token. What was getting me was that you can't use 'me' you have to use a userid. Now I just have to see if I can get my friends' status.

Comment: This doesn't work, as it turns out, as the access_token dosen't all for getting status, only posting. I still need a solution for getting status.